# error Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'XXX' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am getting this error, I am sure I have matched with the same name.
please help me

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute"

this is index.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/taglibs.jsp" %>


<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <form:form  action="dummy" method="post" commandName="userForm">

                <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Spring MVC Form Demo - Registration</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td>
                    <form:input path="username" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Profession:</td>
                    <td><form:select path="profession" items="${professionList}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form:form>

            </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the file DummyControllor.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;



/**
 * @author ***
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dummy.htm")
public class DummyController extends AbstractGCEController {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewRegistration(Model model) {
        User userForm = new User();
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);

        List<String> professionList = new ArrayList<>();
        professionList.add("Developer");
        professionList.add("Designer");
        professionList.add("IT Manager");
        model.addAttribute("professionList", professionList);

        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user, Map<String, Object> model) {

        // implement your own registration logic here...

        // for testing purpose:
        System.out.println("username: " + user.getUsername());
        System.out.println("profession: " + user.getProfession());

        return "RegistrationSuccess";
    }

}
```

The User.java

```
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String profession;

    public User() {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public User(String username, String profession) {

        this.username = username;
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

}
```

the registrationSuccess.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body><%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Registration Success</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Registration Succeeded!</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <h3>Thank you for registering! Here's the review of your details:</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td>${userForm.username}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Profession:</td>
                <td>${userForm.profession}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: Your jsp is called registrationSuccess but your request mapping is dummy.html , try changing the request mapping to registrationSuccess

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to hit? Are you hitting the controller url or directly the JSP url?